# Implement favorites documents in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My data model contains two objects - User and Product (stored in mongodb). I have already built a faceted product search using elasticsearch. Now I'm struggling with implementation of "favorite products" - user can mark some products as *his* favorite and then when searching they should be at the top of the list. The question is - how to model this favorite products marking to make search aware of it and to be able to perform correct sort operation?

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess - without having tried it. And you know how finicky elasticsearch queries can be. So feel free to try and let us have feedback.

In your code, extract the document IDs that the user has as favorites (from your user data model). Then use the elasticsearch constant_score to promote those that are marked as favorite, by adding this clause into your existing bool query (or however you are searching your products already).

```
{
  "constant_score" : {
     "ids" : {
        "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
     }
  }
}
```

Feel free to edit your question or this response with more details about your query if this is anywhere close to the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach parent\child document is described in this [article](http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/)

I found it very helpfull while ivestigating imlementation of the same feature. But I don't know its drawbacks, as i'am not implemented it yet.